# Unable to Verify Custom Domain with Firebase Using Namecheap

Tags: firebase

After I followed the instruction by inserting the Text Record 1 that firebase has provided into my NameCheap, this error message keeps popping up:

Current Status: Sorry, we were unable to verify your domain.

This message has been shown up for about 5 days now.

I've captured screenshots of firebase and namecheap setting as below:

[image]

[image]

After @Frank van Puffelen suggested to change the host value from my domain name to @, this is the screenshot, and we'll wait and see after a few hours, hopefully it can verify successfully.

[image]

After waiting for a few hours this message appears:

[image]

Comment: [update Feb 24, 2021] Firebase had a known issue with false domain-verification failures. More info here https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Hosting/21001

Description: We believe the issue with Firebase Hosting is partially resolved. No user action is required at this time.

Affected users should not have any issues navigating into Hosting via the console, but might still see a "Verify" button in the Firebase Hosting console. While the domain might look like it's not verified, hosted content serving should not be affected. Clicking on the

Answer (score 121, accepted):

From other reports and the information on this [Google page for verifying namecheap domains](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6142985?hl=en), it looks like you may have to use `@` for the host field.

> In the Namecheap site, click **Manage** next to the domain you want to
>   verify with your Google service.
>
> 1. Click the **Advanced DNS** tab on the domain dashboard.
> 2. Scroll down and click **Add New Record** under the host records table.
> 3. Select **TXT Record** from the record type drop-down list.
> 4. Paste the entire verification record into the **Value** field.
> 5. Enter @ in the **Host** field.
> 6. Leave the **TTL** field set to Automatic.
> 7. Click the green check mark to save your TXT record.
>
> Note: The change may take up to 24 hours to update. However, as you go
>   through the next steps in the Setup Wizard, the wizard immediately
>   starts checking for your new TXT record to verify your domain.

Can you try that? If it doesn't work, let me know and also reach out to support@firebase.com.

Comment: I just sent you an email to support@firebase.com. thanks

Comment: After Frank suggestion, everything is working great. Thank you Frank.

Comment: This worked for me using a Squarespace domain too, after a short delay

Comment: For Godaddy domain, seems I have to add BOTH original host txt record and `@` host record.

Answer (score 44):

Your attached screens do not show your CNAME configuration. Even though firebase instructions indeed only asks for two TXT records, records that are both correctly set up as your screens show, I believe that these pair of TXT records that firebase requests do not free you up from the need of setting up at least a CNAME record in addition to both TXT records.

This was my case: while I did not set a CNAME record, firebase never recognized my domain.

I am not an expert (sorry!), but in the lack of other answers, even I may be helpful to suggest that you set up your CNAME record to point to:

```
CNAME record
host: www
value: [yourfirebaseappname].firebaseapp.com.
(Please note the dot after the '.com').
```

In my case this was enough to make firebase works well and recognize my domain.

In my specific case, and I'll register here at least for my own future use, I prefered to use, as an after step, both A records supplied from firebase as my way to route to my domain without www.

I believe this can be done with CNAME, but in my case the final setup was:

```
Advanced DNS Management
type: CNAME record
host: www
value: [my-domain-name-without-www]

type: A record
host: @
value: [IP address from firebase, like '1.2.3.4']

type: A record
host: @
value: [Second IP address from firebase, like '2.3.4.5']
```

Everything is working fine using this configuration. Goal reached.

As a todo future step, It would be useful to learn how to achieve similar goal using the CNAME record pointing to firebase domain instead of A records pointing to firebase supplied IP addresses.

Hope this helps other users in similar situation!

Comment: Adding the CNAME was the final missing piece for me

Comment: I am getting a Following notice:
There was a problem connecting your custom domain.

Comment: This worked for me. I had a CNAME record for my domain, but the value was different (some namecheap address). Changing it to myappname.firebaseapp.com worked. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, changed the namecheap CNAME to `myapp.firebase.com.` waited a minute and it worked.

Answer (score 16):

I had issues connecting my custom domain as well, apart from using @ in the host field and the CNAME, you'd also need A records. Here's all I ended up with, I sat back a while for the domain to get propagated (I had just purchased it) and waited for 10 minutes after adding all of the records and it worked. Also I've found helpful instructions in [this blog](https://www.macariojames.com/blog/2018/02/19/firebase-custom-domain-verification-namecheap-dns/) post.

[image]

Comment: What are those IPs from?

Comment: They are all for Google's Firebase servers, you can check their docs in case any of those changed.

Comment: Thanks. The CNAME record is actually unnecessary. You can simply use `www` in the A records instead of `www.yourdomain.com`.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and I took Namecheap support. Then they provided me following properties to change when connecting Namecheap with Firebase.

1. For the TXT records Host should be @ instead of **yourdomain.com**
2. For the CNAME records remove the trailing domain name from the Host.

   In this example **value** should be

   **firebase1._domainkey**

   and not

   **firebase1._domainkey.yourdomain.com**

Comment: thanks... i was going crazy. i forgot about the .yourdomain.com part xD

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue for days (my custom domain made it through the verification stage but would not connect) but it turns out that I didn't have to change my DNS configuration to fix it (the screenshot for the config that worked is below for reference).

I just had to re-run the Connect Domain wizard. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

> Hosting -> Select the vertical ellipsis under your custom domain -> delete domain -> then click Connect Domain to start the wizard again.

namecheap dns configuration
[image: screenshot]

Lookup your domain using this tool to see if there are DNS errors https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/

Answer (score 2):

For me (with namecheap) I had to remove all existing records, then the TXT record alone worked.
Reference: this [post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-firebase-hosting-custom-domain-the-missing-manual-7f971c3c2d1e)

Answer (score 1):

That configuration worked for me. Seems the easiest and propagation takes around 20 minutes (include your TXT verification as well, of course).

[image: namecheap DNS for Firebase Hosting]