# Custom domain verification failing with dreamhost and firebase

Tags: dns, firebase, firebase-hosting

The custom domain verification is not working with Dreamhost hosted domain. The instructions specify to add the DNS TXT entries at domain registrar. But since the domain is hosted on dreamhost, domain registrar (GoDaddy) doesn't allow to edit the DNS entries. So I created DNS entries at the dreamhost panel. But even after 48 hours the verification keeps failing. Any ideas why?

I checked a similar question here but it doesn't help -

[Unable to Verify Custom Domain with Firebase Using Namecheap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979673/unable-to-verify-custom-domain-with-firebase-using-namecheap)

Comment: `dig -t txt +noall +answer <your domain>` If that doesn't contain the TXT records, Firebase will not be able to find your domain. If it does contain the correct TXT records, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).

Comment: Thank you Frank. Yes it does contain TXT records. I've sent out a note via the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

For gandi, you need to do the following (pro tip: edit your zone file in expert mode, it's simpler to understand what is being saved)

```
@ 10800 IN TXT "firebase=SITE_NAME"
@ 10800 IN TXT "globalsign-domain-verification=KEY"
```