# Adding custom hosting domain: "Unexpected TXT records found. Continuing to watch for changes."

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I'm attempting to add a custom domain to firebase hosting.

Added the TXT records as instructed, and I get this message in the firebase dashboard:

"Unexpected TXT records found. Continuing to watch for changes."

There is one additional TXT record in my DNS settings, but I can't remove it. I don't see how it would get in the way of firebase's verification of my domain either.

I'm using Namecheap if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had to make sure that for the host field, it was set to '@', and not my actual host name.

I'm told this varies from registrar to registrar. Some require '@' for the host field if it's for the root domain, and others do not.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have this exact issue on Namecheap/firebase. Did you set host to `@` for both `globalsign-domain` and `firebase=`?

Comment: Yes I did. For CNAME, however, I used 'www', and '*'.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got the verification complete but get stuck on Step 3. For CNAME, I cannot figure out how to get it to work. For my project currently CNAME has host `www.shipthem.me` and value `shippymcshipface.firebaseapp.com` But nothing is happening? I tried putting `www` in host. Can you please specify what your CNAME looks like? Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Yep, I used 'www', and '*'. I would revert back to WWW then wait a half a day and see if maybe it's just taking a while to propagate.

Comment: I should also mention that I updated the A records as well to point to the supplied IP addresses. This seemed to resolve an issue where www.mysite.com would work but, mysite.com would not.

Comment: Thank you, currently I have seen no change http://tinypic.com/r/2rz5gmx/9

Comment: I've seen this as reference and the google's namecheap article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979673/unable-to-verify-custom-domain-with-firebase-using-namecheap

Comment: Hmmm. I'm stumped, your DNS page looks identical to mine, except I have TTL set to automatic for everything. I also noticed that my domains have a period on the end for the CNAME records. So like 'someproject.firebaseapp.com.' Yours is cut off so you might already have that. Sorry I can't be of more help!!

Comment: My domain Provider is only allowing @ , but i am not able to get the domain verified... what should i do :(

Comment: @ScriptKitty try adding a dot after the value: `shippymcshipface.firebaseapp.com.`

Answer (score 4):

If you've updated your TXT records in your DNS settings as per the instructions, then it just a matter of time for firebase to detect the changes. Normally upto 48 hours. This message is normal though, if there is a real problem then you will be able to see an error message after the 48 hours.

Comment: I believe on firebase they state 24 hours. I've gotten some kind of error afterwards though

Answer (score 4):

On namecheap what worked was changing my host field to '@' rather than the host provided on firebase help.

Next step was to wait for an SSL

Comment: This is what finally worked for me. It had been over 48 hours, but once I found this thread and changed it, worked in 30 minutes.