# Adding custom domain (crazydomains): Unexpected TXT records found. Continuing to watch for changes

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I've added the TXT records according to firebase's instructions.  Also had crazydomains support verify the settings, but I'm still getting the Unexpected TXT records found. Continuing to watch for changes. message at the Verify step.

Anyone had experience doing this with crazydomains? I've read on another similar post targeted at NAMECHEAP, but I don't see how I can add the '@' to the Host field with crazydomains.

Here is my settings on crazydomains.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding custom hosting domain: "Unexpected TXT records found. Continuing to watch for changes."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892312/adding-custom-hosting-domain-unexpected-txt-records-found-continuing-to-watch)

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  It's similar.  That post was more targeted towards Namecheap's set up.  I don't get to play with the Host field in crazydomains.

Answer (score 5):

Google support staff (Neel) provided a solution that worked. Basically redoing the steps, but in a timely manner.

1. On the Firebase console, delete your custom domain.
2. Remove TXT records in the DNS and then save the changes. 
   (Then wait for at least 5-10 minutes before doing the next step)
3. On the Firebase console, add again your custom domain.
4. Add the TXT records in the DNS and then save the changes