# How to Connect a Custom Domain to a Firebase Project?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I have my domain listed at Namecheap and my angualr app on firebase. I added the A records to my DNS settings on Namecheap a couple days ago, but I'm still not seeing any of my content on my domain. Am I missing any part of the process?

Comment: Unless it is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39988961) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com//37892312), it is likely that your settings haven't propagated or are wrong. But with the information you shared there's nothing we can check. I recommend that you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your host is '@' not the domain name for the A records. I made that mistake not too long ago.