# Firebase: Cannot Verify Ownership of Namecheap Domain

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, namecheap

I'm having trouble verifying namecheap domain with firebase hosting

> Tried to follow this posts instructions without success:
>   [Unable to Verify Custom Domain with Firebase Using Namecheap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979673/unable-to-verify-custom-domain-with-firebase-using-namecheap)
>   and this 
>   [Adding custom hosting domain: "Unexpected TXT records found. Continuing to watch for changes."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892312/adding-custom-hosting-domain-unexpected-txt-records-found-continuing-to-watch?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So my definitions are like this:

```
Type: TXT Record
Host: @
Value: globalsign-domain-verification=...
TTL: Automatic

Type: TXT Record
Host: @
Value: firebase=mydomain.info
TTL: Automatic

Type: CNAME Record
Host: www
Value: myprojectname.firebaseapp.com.
TTL: Automatic

Type: A Record
Host: @
Value: First IP Address retrieved with MXToolbox
TTL: Automatic

Type: A Record
Host: @
Value: Second IP Address retrieved with MXToolbox
TTL: Automatic
```

When I execute "dig -t txt +noall +answer mydomain.info", it returns:

```
mydomain.info.      1798    IN  TXT "globalsign-domain-verification=..."
mydomain.info.      1798    IN  TXT "firebase=myprojectname"
```

(It has the extra dot at the end of the domain)

But still in firebase dashboard I have this message:

```
Verifying ownership
Unexpected TXT records found. Continuing to watch for changes.

and later:

Verification failed
Couldn't find the correct TXT records in your DNS records
```

I'm trying to solve this problem for several days now.

Comment: Unless you share enough details so that we can check the DNS records, there is not much any of us here can do. In cases like this it is usually best to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/), where we can provide personalized help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly recommend that you contact Firebase support. I had a similar issue going on for days and only after they manually intervened behind the scenes it was resolved. Good luck...

Answer (score 3):

After not having my domain verify for over 24 hours and trying numerous things, I eventually deleted the CNAME record of `[projectname].firebaseapp.com`. A few minutes later, it verified with no problem.

These are the steps that they want you to do:

- Only have the TXT Record for the verification.
- After verification, add two A Records.

This is what I did:

- Add TXT record and two A records.
- Get verified

Hope this helps. I submitted a ticket to firebase to propose that they modify the instructions to make it clear that **you can't put the CNAME to your project URL**.

Comment: I can vouch for this - the TXT record must be the _only_ record on your DNS. Any A or CNAME records will cause your verification to fail.

Comment: Worked instantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. instead of domain, I used @ in host and it worked. I am on a Free plan.

Answer (score 0):

Always ensure that you are using a paid version of Firebase. Domains do not get verified if you are using a free account. I had to downgrade one of my old projects in order to verify my new project. Apparently, firebase allows only a certain number of projects to be upgraded to a blaze plan. I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the firebase docs that says this?  I searched but couldn't verify that info.

Comment: I couldn't find it in the docs either. But faced the connection problem for days. And when I upgraded the same project, it got connected within minutes! This happened to me twice.