# Do I need my domain to be in HTTPS to use it as a custom domain for hosting Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

It's been three days that I still wait for validation of my domain name. 
I have this error:

```
"Unexpected TXT records were found. Continued search for changes".
```

Because of this, I checked, but everything is correct. I wonder if it is the fact that my domain is not accessible in HTTPS.

Comment: the TXT records are corrects

Comment: DNS entries are unrelated to whether your domain is accessible via HTTPS. If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892312/adding-custom-hosting-domain-unexpected-txt-records-found-continuing-to-watch?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979673/unable-to-verify-custom-domain-with-firebase-using-namecheap) doesn't help, I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

Recheck your TXT-records once again and then try to restart the verification process.

The fact that your domain is not accessible via an `https://` secure connection is **no problem**. Firebase is even going to provide a SSL certificate for your domain once validated.

If the error still persist you should consider contacting the Firebase Support instead of the stackoverflow community, as they are definitely going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Perform following steps. It may help you

- Remove/Delete your custom domain from the Firebase Console
- In the DNS, Remove the TXT records and save it.
- Now, add you custom domain again into your Firebase Console
- In the DNS add the TXT records again and save the changes.

After completing this operation, "Unexpected TXT records were found. Continued search for changes" error will be terminated permanently.